# Using SPServices to update SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint

I want to change a property of a SharePoint list item with given input. I used the documentation and got this, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There could be something completely wrong because I'm not too experienced.

```
$().SPServices(
        {
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "TechInv",
            Number: itemNumber,
            valuepairs: [[property, replacement]],
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                // ...
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

The SPServices plugin is [well documented](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems&referringTitle=Lists). In your case, it seems that you are missing the item ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug (addon of Firefox) or the web toolbar of your browser to look at the query that is sent to the server, as well as the error message returns by the server. That way you can more easily find where the issue is.
In your case you used "Number" instead of "ID" I think.

BTW, I created a Sharepoint API in JavaScript that is, I think, easier to use than SPServices. It's there : [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$().SPServices(
    {
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "TechInv",
        ID: itemNumber,
        valuepairs: [[property, replacement]],
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            // ...
        }
 });
```

ID is the change and it should work.

Comment: Every entry in the list has a unique string "XXX-XXXX" that goes in the first column and that's what itemNumber is. So are you saying that ID will take itemNumber and check for matches in the first column and get the item that corresponds to it?

Comment: Also, switching it to ID made it pass through with no errors but it didn't do anything to the list.